# algorithm2e, caption space

Tags: spacing, captions, ieeetran

I am using the package `algorithm2e` within the IEEEtran class.
I need to provide a space between the caption and the Algoritm.
Currently, the caption is very close to the algorithm.
Is there any command to accomplish this?

```
\documentclass[journal,dvips]{IEEEtran}    

\usepackage{algorithm2e}    % Package for writing algoritms
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\@algocf@capt@plain}{above}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\SetAlgoLined
\LinesNumbered
\DontPrintSemicolon
\KwData{System dynamics }
\KwResult{Reachable }
$K \leftarrow \lceil t_f/r \rceil$\;

\caption{Analysis of a test algorithm to introduce my question to the community.}
\label{alg:anl}
\end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using `IEEEtran` or `article`? If the former, please update your example code.

Comment: ...also, you're already setting/adjusting the `\AlCapSkip` length that designates the distance/space between the algorithm and the caption.

Comment: How should I implement {\AlCapSkip} in the code above?. When I use \SetAlCapSkip{10ex} the space is added before the caption but I would like the space after the caption becuase I am placing the caption on top the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only do you need to adjust the placement of the `plain` style (`\@algocf@capt@plain`), you also need to adjust the construction of the caption (``):

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@algocf@capt@plain}{above}
\renewcommand{\algocf@caption@plain}{\box\algocf@capbox\vskip\AlCapSkip}%
\makeatother

\setlength{\AlCapSkip}{1em}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \LinesNumbered
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwData{System dynamics}
  \KwResult{Reachable}
  $K \leftarrow \lceil t_f/r \rceil$\;
  \caption{Analysis of a test algorithm to introduce my question to the community.}
  \label{alg:anl}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

It is assumed that a `plain` style will set the caption below, so adjustment of the caption-setting macro is necessary. I just switched around the placement of the `\algocf@capbox` and the space.

Adjust the length/distance `\AlCapSkip` to suite your needs.